# Comparing two fields in a query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, where-clause, criteria

Hi I have a query and I want to compare two fields and if their value is S then I have field called Sum where I want add the value 1 and if the fields value are different or one field is null then I want the Sum field to show 0

Something like this :

```
SumR: IIf([Forms]![FrmDSTResultsCompare]![Test1] And [Test1] = S,"1","0")
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What you really want to do is unclear.

Comment: What is the source of "And [Test1] "?  Is it a table column in msaccess?  or is it just a repeat of the Forms field?  What is "SumR" ?  Is it another Forms field?  or is it a table column?  Where does "query" come into play?  What is the need for SQL?  All inputs and outputs need to be identified and shared with us.  It is very difficult for us to guess.

Comment: `S` needs to be in quote marks and the numbers not. Field is called SumR, not Sum. As is. `Forms!FrmDSTResultsCompare!Test1` must be a True or False value. Is the form control UNBOUND? `IIf([Forms]![FrmDSTResultsCompare]![Test1] ="S" And [Test1] = "S", 1, 0)`